# How to add a string of numbers to multiple text files in a directory?

Tags: shell, files, solaris, rename

file.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

I want to add  99999 to the begining of the all the file names without changing anything else in the file name in solaris 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "99999$f"; done
```